# Unable to Connect to RDS via HaProxy

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, haproxy

I have a MariaDB RDS set up in a VPC. The RDS is not publicly accessible. Therefore in order to access the RDS, I've decided to spawn an EC2 in the same VPC and configured HAProxy.

HAProxy is working fine and is listening to port 3306. However when I attempt to connect to RDS via HAProxy, I'm getting this error message:

`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 2`

Here's my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log     global
    mode    tcp
    option  tcplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen rds
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server rds test.dkd20slksdfkl.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 check
```

In case you're wondering, I did edit `/etc/default/haproxy` and put `ENABLED=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to connect to the RDS successfully by removing the `check` option. I'm not sure why but perhaps because there's no other RDS to load balance, therefore the `check` option would give problem instead.

Comment: That suggests that the checks were not succeeding, so HAProxy was accepting the incoming connection and immediately closing it due to no available healthy back-ends.  Using `option log-health-checks`, reviewing your HAProxy logs, or checking the backend health via the stats UI or the stats socket would make this problem apparent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. So far the connection is good and I'll continue to monitor. Should I see anymore problem I'll enable the health check log.